# LazyVim LSP ignore errors

Tags: python, neovim, nvim-lspconfig, pycodestyle

I'm attempting to configure pylsp to ignore or modify certain errors such as line length. Following the documentation for pylsp and lazyvim, I have created a `pylspignore.lua` file and placed it in my `~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/` directory. In my `pylspingore.lua` file I have the following

```
require("lspconfig").pylsp.setup({
  settings = {
    pylsp = {
      plugins = {
        pycodestyle = {
          ignore = { "W391" },
          maxLineLength = 100,
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

However now whenever I run `:healthcheck` I see the following errors:

```
lazy: require("lazy.health").check()

lazy.nvim ~
- OK Git installed
- OK no existing packages found by other package managers
- OK packer_compiled.lua not found
- ERROR Issues were reported when loading your specs:
- ERROR Invalid spec module: `plugins.pycodestyle-ignore`
- ERROR Expected a `table` of specs, but a `boolean` was returned instead
```

Can someone please suggest where I have gone wrong in setting up my LSP?